# Initializing a variable dependent on type in template parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constants, typename

I have a class with a static const variable that I need to initialize differently depending on the variable type in the template parameter.  Is there a way to do this without specialization?

In my header file I have:

```
template<class Item>
class CircularQueue {
public:
    static const Item EMPTY_QUEUE;
    ...
```

Attempting to initialize it in the .cpp file:

```
template<typename Item> const Item CircularQueue<Item>::EMPTY_QUEUE = Item("-999");
```

I'd like it to initialize to -999 whether it's an int, double, or string. However, in the code above I get a "cast from 'const char' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive]" error.

Comment: Maybe create an templated initialization helper that can be specialized instead. `template<class T> class Initializer { ... };`

Comment: Nope, you need specialization. You don't need to specialize the entire `CircularQueue` template class, but you can use a separate, specialized helper class to initialize `EMPTY_QUEUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing an example of using a separate helper class that can be specialized, instead of having to specialize this entire template class, since you mentioned you'd like to see an example of this approach.

Just declare a separate template class that sets the default value, and specialize it for `std::string`.

```
template<class Item> class defaultItem {

public:

    static constexpr Item default_value() { return -999; }
};

template<> class defaultItem<std::string> {

public:
    static constexpr const char *default_value() { return "-999"; }
};
```

You don't have to use the `constexpr` keyword, if your C++ compiler is not of a recent vintage. You can also define the same specialization for a `const char *`, rather than a `std::string`, if needed.

Then, your main class simply defines `EMPTY_QUEUE` as:

```
template<typename Item>
const Item CircularQueue<Item>::EMPTY_QUEUE =
           defaultItem<Item>::default_value();
```